# UIView Positioning for iPhone: Any concept of "Z-Index"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I know if I want to add a black background to a UIImageView, I can create an UIImageView that is a bit smaller than the UIView it's contained in. If I do this, the UIImageView is positioned on top of the black background.

Just hypothetically speaking, suppose I want the black background UIView on TOP of the UIImageView (so that it covers the image), how do I do this? Is there a concept of a z-index?

Here's my code to add a black background to an image:

```
UIView *blackBG = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];

blackBG.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIImageView *myPicture = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                          [UIImage imageNamed: @"myPicture.jpg"]];

int borderWidth = 10;

myPicture.frame = CGRectMake(borderWidth,
                             borderWidth,
                             blackBG.frame.size.width-borderWidth*2,
                             blackBG.frame.size.height-borderWidth*2)];

[blackBG addSubview: myPicture];
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Subviews are layered, you can send a subview to the back with...

```
[myView sendSubviewToBack:mySubView];
```

or bringSubviewToFront etc.

You can also do one of these...

```
[myView insertSubview:mySubview atIndex:0]; //Places it at the bottom

[myView insertSubview:mySubview belowSubview:anotherSubview]; //Places it below anotherSubview
```

As soon as you add a view as a subview to another view however, the parent view is the bottom of the stack. You can play around with CALayer z orders but you are bypassing the general approach of views and subviews.

Create a single view as a parent for both the bg view and the imageview, then you can order them how you like.

**UPDATE:** I have a UIView+Layout category which has nice `[subview sendToBack];` and `[subview bringToFront];` which you may find useful.... [article here](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/how-categories-can-simplify-your-code/)

Comment: +1 On top of @Simon Lee's answer. The addSubview method should add the subview to the top without copying the object. So previously when I've had only one or two items within a view I've just called addSubview on the other item to bring it up above. This is rather unconventional however.